# Merging/interlacing two matrices

Tags: matlab, merge, matrix

I have two matrices, say A and B, each are 133x365.

I want to create a new matrix which contains the first column of A then the first column of B, second column of A then second column of B, and so on.

I think it is some sort of concatenation but I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [matlab - how to merge/interlace 2 matrices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142251/matlab-how-to-merge-interlace-2-matrices)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
reshape(permute(cat(3,A,B), [1 3 2]), [m 2*n]);
```

where [m,n] = size(A)