# How can I join two variables into one taking values one by one?

Tags: matlab, vector

How can I join two variables into one variable taking values by turn, in Matlab? Namely, taking one from the first, then one from the second, then again from the first...

For example, to join

```
1
2
3
```

and

```
4
5
6
```

into

```
1
4
2
5
3
6
```

Maybe it is very basic question, but I am new to Matlab. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question: [matlab - how to merge/interlace 2 matrices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142251/matlab-how-to-merge-interlace-2-matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate them vertically as row vectors and then convert the result back into a column:

```
reshape([x(:), y(:)]', [], 1)
```

#### Example

```
x = (1:3)';
y = (4:6)';
reshape([x(:), y(:)]', [], 1)
```

This results in:

```
ans =
     1
     4
     2
     5
     3
     6
```

Comment: Thank you! Just, it also worked for me as you wrote before editing the answer: 
`c = [a(:)'; b(:)'];  
c = c(:)`

Comment: I know, but this is shorter and more elegant.