# Extracting Columns iteratively from 2 different m-by-n matrices and concatenating in a set of n different m-by-2 matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, memory, matrix

**MATLAB:**

In MATLAB,

I have **2**   *m-by-n*   matrices, A and B. I want to make a set of **n**

*m-by-2*   matrices such as in **ith** matrix (of set of **n**), first column will be **ith**

column from A and second column will be **ith** column from B.

How to extract and concatenate **ith** columns from both matrices?

How I can store these **n** matrices? Using loops? (Memory?)

**Example:**

Input:

A = [ 1, 2, 3; 4, 5 ,6; 7, 8, 9] (3x3 matrix)

B = [ 11, 22, 33; 44, 55 ,66; 77, 88, 99] (3x3 matrix)

Output:

For i=1:3

C1 = [1, 11; 4, 44; 7, 77]

C2 = [2, 22; 5, 55; 8, 88]

C3 = [3, 33; 6, 66; 9, 99]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think you might be looking for interleaving columns of the two matrices. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142251/matlab-how-to-merge-interlace-2-matrices shows how to interleave rows. To convert it to columns, first transpose `A` and `B`, then transpose the result.

Comment: @Schorsch I think I improved my question by adding an example.    Please see, is my question clear now ?

Comment: Use concatenation and `permute` to build a 3D array, rather than `n` separate matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'm going to do is change your variable names. Mainly this is just to make referring to the variables easier, especially as **m** and **n** change. Instead of writing

```
C1(:,:)
C2(:,:)
...
Cn(:,:)
```

I'm going to write

```
C(:,:,1)
C(:,:,2)
...
C(:,:,n)
```

All I've done is moved the index from the variable name to the index of the 3rd dimension.

Now, to create the `C` array:

```
A = [ 1, 2, 3; 4, 5 ,6; 7, 8, 9]
B = [ 11, 22, 33; 44, 55 ,66; 77, 88, 99]

[m,n]=size(A)

C = reshape([A',B']', m, 2, n)
```

The output of this is:

```
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

B =

   11   22   33
   44   55   66
   77   88   99

m =  3
n =  3
C =

ans(:,:,1) =

    1   11
    4   44
    7   77

ans(:,:,2) =

    2   22
    5   55
    8   88

ans(:,:,3) =

    3   33
    6   66
    9   99
```

As you can see, `C(:,:,1)` is equal to `C1` in your example, `C(:,:,2) = C2` and so on. And this extends without change as the sizes of `A` and `B` change. You never have to come up with new variable names. And all you have to do to know how many *m-by-2* matrices you've got is

```
numVars = size(C,3);
```

Note: This uses the same technique found in the answer here: [matlab - how to merge/interlace 2 matrices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142251/matlab-how-to-merge-interlace-2-matrices)