# By using for loop command take values from several matrices to build a new matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 matrices like

```
A=[1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12] ; 
B=[2 3 5 7; 8 9 7 6; 8 7 6 5]
```

and I have to create a new matrix  like the following:

```
C=[1 2 2 3 3 4 5 7; 5 6 8 9 7 8 7 6; 9 10 8 7 11 12 6 5]
```

i.e my new matrix will should be built with 1st 2 column from A ,then first 2 column of B and then last 2 column of A and next last 2 column of B.

Can anyone help me on solving this problem **through "for loop statement".**

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: This problem is already solved, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142251/matlab-how-to-merge-interlace-2-matrices or http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/interleave_matrices or use reshape.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need for loop for this. What you want to achieve is to interleave two matrices, you can do it manually

```
C = [A(:, [1 2]), B(:, [1 2]), A(:, [3 4]), B(:, [3 4])];
```

Or you can make it into a more general solution:

```
function out = interleave(m1, m2, step)
out = [reshape(m1, [numel(m1)/step step]); reshape(m2, [numel(m2)/step step])];
out = reshape( out, [size(m1,1) numel(out)/size(m1,1)]);
end
```

Then

```
C = interleave(A,B,2)
```

will give you the result you want.

Comment: ......thanks a lot for the answer but I want to use for loop because right now I am working on 12x36 matrix so that I can build this matrix by a single comand.

Comment: Do you mean you have two matrices, each having 12 rows and 36 columns, that you want to interleave ? Why would that require a for loop ?

Comment: .........Actually right now I am solving 4th order 2D FEM problem in matlab................you are right that for making a small matrix i dont need for loop but If I have 3 matrices with 12X12 matrices and I have to do interleave between them 3 times i.e after every 4 columns I have to take another 4 columns form other matrix and then 4 form another one and so on until tahe new matrix become 12X36.................Thanks